# Is there any way to resolve Ember routes, controllers, components from custom directory?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Is there any way to resolve Ember routes, controllers, components etc from custom directory and fallback to default `app` directory when not found?

Answer (score 3):

you'd probably want to look in https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-resolver 
fork that, customize the logic to your needs, and then use it in your project.

Alternatively, there is module unification, which offers a more natural way of organizing files -- it's not quite finished yet -- progress is tracked here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/16373